# MultiTableInputFormat to compare 2 tables taking about 80 mins

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am using Hbase MultiTableInputFormat to compare 2 tables: Table1 (7 million), Table2 (30 million).

In the driver, i am passing to scans ( without any filters). In my mapper i am doing a compare and writing the summary in Reducer.

Any settings specific to this scenario that might speed up the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you used scanner caching, it can increase performance -
example - scan.setCaching(1000);